# How could I pull the data from this XML with AJAX and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I specifically want to pull one of these node which represents a folder of images. The node I am referring to is channelimagepath. Thanks in advance.

Here is the XML file:

```
<channel title="My Title">
    <shortname>aa_aaperil</shortname>
    <artist>Aesthetic Apparatus</artist>
    <channellogosmall>images/asp.jpg</channellogosmall>
    <channelimagepath>images/base/flash/aa_aaperil/</channelimagepath>
    <channeldesign>images/channel/aa_aaperil/aa_aaperil-design.gif</channeldesign>
    <totalimagesback>100</totalimagesback>
    <totalimagesmiddle>100</totalimagesmiddle>
    <totalimagesfront>100</totalimagesfront>
    <pagepath>/artistchannel.php/channel/aa_aaperil</pagepath>
    <description><![CDATA[Here's the description.]]></description>
    <allowblocking>true</allowblocking>
</channel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
folder=yourXMLHTTPObject.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("channelimagepath");
theFolderYouWant=folder[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

do you need the ajax part as well?

Comment: I tried this an it didn't work was it because the folder's path is already in the XML node?

Comment: as soren mentioned, it's still text...maybe you want something like `document.getElementById('theDivYouWantToAddTheImageTo').innerHTML+=<img src=\"+theFolderYouWant+\"/>'` after the above lines?

Comment: wait...if you're expecting a graphic, maybe you want the `channeldesign` entry instead?

Answer (score 0):

Some variation of

```
var blah = '';
$(xml).find("channelimagepath").each(function(){
    blah = $(this).text();
  });
```

Comment: Thank Soren I have tried that but isn't .text() just for text? This node is of images.

Comment: The imagepath in the xml document you show in your question is just a path name to the image, not the image itself.  hence it would still be TEXT.  Even if you had the actual image encoded (like as a base64 encoding) then that would also be text.